# Rotate a UIButton that I pulled from a NSArray

Tags: ios, uibutton, nsarray

I am trying to apply a transformation to a Button that I have pulled from a Array:

```
buttonArray[y].transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
```

but it doesn't like this... Is there a different way for me to do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.0);
[[buttonArray[y] layer] setAffineTransform:rotate];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use CATransform3D**

Add

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(d) (d * M_PI / 180)
```

in .pch file

```
CATransform3D myTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
myTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -500;
myTransform = CATransform3DRotate(myTransform, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
myView.layer.transform = myTransform;
```

you can go on changing the angle here DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90) **Hope this will help you**